# WPF application to complete JQuery element of a website

Tags: c#, jquery, wpf, mshtml

I'm trying to create a WPF application that loads a webpage, auto-completes a series of fields, and then submits. To do this, I've followed Microsoft's guide here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Automation-Loading-6ae6c88a

This works fine for completing regular html text boxes. However, the web form I'm trying to complete contains a button that opens up a jQuery form (namely: ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all modalDialog shadow).

I can't seem to work out how to complete the fields in this jQuery form?

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not do a POST directly? Makes more sense to me.

Comment: The user needs to verify the contents of the form and modify if desired. I'd like to make the user experience similar to what the users currently have via the web form; they don't like change. I'm just trying to reduce the time spent by the user filling out the form.